# Laravel Relation with Pivot Table, Relationships?

Tags: laravel, pivot-table, relationship

I have a User-Tables aswell as an "Adress" Table. They can enter multiple Adresses to choose from when checking out.

Now I want to be able to have one adress set as the standard invoice adresse and another one as the standard invoise adress. I thought about doing it using a pivot table, containing the following:

```
Schema::create('users_adresses_pivot', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->integer('invoice_adress_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('invoice_adress_id')->references('id')->on('adresses');
        $table->integer('delivery_adress_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('delivery_adress_id')->references('id')->on('adresses');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

However I'm not sure if thats the right way. It looks a bit like a bad practice to me. If I choose this option how do I set the Relations? Because I would need two Relations from User to Adresses. I already got one in order to foreach through them in a view. So If I replaced that with the Pivot Relation I could only get the standard invoice & delivery adresses instead of the others too. Any idea?

This is my current Relationship:
User.php:

```
public function adresses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Adress');
    }
```

Adress.php:

```
 public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO dont use a pivot table, you dont need a many to many, this is a simple one to many relationship (one user has many addresses).

In the address table you just need to add two columns: "user_id" and "type". 
The relations you wrote are good.

Comment: Yes you are right. 1 upvote for catching my mistakes.

Comment: never see you doing a mistake Eddy, but ty for the upvote. Hope this answer helps @Scarwolf

Comment: But wait. Many to Many woudl mean an adress could belong to many users. That's wrong because those are the adresses they create from themself. I just want to add something which tells mee that this adress is either their standard delivery address, standard invoice address, both or none.

Comment: You designed a pivot table, a pivot table is for many to many. Just add two boolean fields on addresses table: invoice and delivery

Comment: Yeah that sounds like the best way. Thanks! Not my day.